# Print pdf booklet with not double sided printer with nodejs pdf-lib and Edge

Tags: node.js, pdf, printing, microsoft-edge

I have a cheap Epson inkjet color printer, and I want to print some A4 format pdf in double sided A5 booklet form.

For example there are a pdf with 8 landscaped pages:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

The printed portrait pages are first sheet is front 1/8, back 2/7, second sheet front 3/6, back 4/5.

The first solution is this, create odd.pdf and even.pdf from original.pdf, print odd.pdf to sheets, then turn the pack, and print even.pdf to the other side.
With https://thecodebarbarian.com/working-with-pdfs-in-node-js.html and pdf-lib, I've made two files. I have opened it with Edge, set 2 pages on one sheet, I have printed it.

```
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs');

run().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function run() {
  const doceven = await PDFDocument.create();
  const docodd  = await PDFDocument.create();

  //var fil= "DROMADER-instrukcje-85958-HU.pdf";
  var fil= "DROMADER-instrukcje-85955-HU.pdf";
  
  const original = await PDFDocument.load( fs.readFileSync('./orig/' + fil ));

  var i;
  var booklet={ pages:original.getPageIndices()
              };

  booklet.count = booklet.pages.length;
  booklet.empty = ( 4 - booklet.count % 4 ) % 4;
  booklet.all = booklet.count + booklet.empty;
  booklet.half = booklet.all / 2;
  booklet.last = booklet.all - 1 ;
  
  //console.log(booklet);
  const originalPageseven = await doceven.copyPages(original, booklet.pages);
  const originalPagesodd = await docodd.copyPages(original, booklet.pages);
  
  for(i=0;i<booklet.half;i++){
        if( i%2==1) {
            docodd.addPage(originalPagesodd[i]);
            docodd.addPage(originalPagesodd[booklet.last-i]);
    } else {
            doceven.addPage(originalPageseven[i]);
            doceven.addPage(originalPageseven[booklet.last-i]);
        }
        //console.log("#", i, booklet.last-i);
  }
  
  // Write the PDF to a file
  fs.writeFileSync('./separated/odd' + fil, await docodd.save());
  fs.writeFileSync('./separated/even' + fil, await doceven.save());
}
```

Problem:

- The margins between two pages on the sheet is wrong positioned, after cutting papers, upper pack has 16mm upper margin, and 6mm bottom margin, the bottom pack has 6mm upper margin, and 16mm bottom margin. Ugly.

Questions:

- Is there any nodejs solution for print pdf bokleted pages to printer directly, and positioning them?
- In Microsoft Edge, is there any way to change margins in case of multiple pages on a sheet?

Comment: Can you please inform us, which exact version of the Edge browser you are using for making this test? I try to check in both **Edge legacy browser** and **Edge Chromium browser** but did not see an option to change margins in case of multiple pages on a sheet. I suggest you try to print with the **default margin** and see whether it shows the same margin for the pages on a sheet.

Comment: Microsoft Edge
Verzió: 87.0.664.66 (Hivatalos build) (64 bites)

Comment: Thanks for informing us of the Edge browser version. I have again checked it but I did not see an option to change margins in case of multiple pages on a sheet. Does it show properly with the default margin?